# Systemd ALWAYS starts my service after 'systemctl stop'

Tags: systemd, service, rhel7

I am running a self-hosted gitea server, managed through a systemd service. However, there is no native way to stop gitea, so I wrote the service file to send a kill -3 signal when I run `sudo systemctl stop gitea`. Unfortunately, when I stop the service, it comes right back up and I can't figure out why.

gitea.service

```
[Unit]
...
[Service]
RestartSec=2s
Type=simple
User=builder
Group=mygroup
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/gitea
ExecStart=/path/to/gitea/binary
Restart=no
KillSignal=3
...
```

I also found that when I am logged in as root, the service will not start back up, so it seems like the service only stays killed as long as the root shell exists (which for sudo is obviously very short)

Any thoughts? I'm required to keep selinux enforcing so there could be some issue there but I have found nothing related to this issue.

Comment: the part title unit is of importance possibly, if you are trying to figure out what restarts the service.  also it could be controlled by a cronjob.  cronjobs can be monitored from /var/log/cron